# Finding the Marginal PDF from a Joint PDF with strange piecewise bounds

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

> I am supposed to show that the marginal PDF of a random variable $Y$ is:
>   $$g(y)= \begin{cases}
> y, & 0<y \le 1\\
> y^{-3}, & y>1\\
> 0, & \textrm{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>   given the joint PDF:
>   $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{4x^3}{y^3}, & 0<x<1, x<y\\
> 0, & \textrm{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$

I know one's supposed to integrate with respect to x, but I am not sure which boundries I should choose, and I can't seem to get the right answer.

Comment: Draw a picture of the region you're supposed to integrate over. That'll help you setup the bounds of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by definition, 
$$
g(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)\ dx. 
$$
There are three cases to consider:

- if $y>1$, then integrate for $x$ on $[0,1]$: $g(y)=\int_{0}^1\dfrac{4x^3}{y^3}\ dx$;
- if $0<y\leq 1$, then integrate for $x$ on $[0,y]$: $g(y)=\int_{0}^y\dfrac{4x^3}{y^3}\ dx$
- if $y<0$, then the integration is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right that you need to integrate with respect to $x.$ However, the joint distribution only has support when $x < y$ and $0<x<1$ so the bounds you need will depend on $y$.

1. If y is negative, then there is no region for $x$ that has support since we need $x<y$ and $x>0.$  So the integral is zero
2. If $0<y<1$, then the upper bound of $x=y$ kicks in before $x=1$ and we only have support for $x\in(0,y).$ So the integration bounds must be $0$ and $y$
3. If $y>1$ then the upper bound of $x=1$ kicks in before $y$ so the bounds are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

The support of the joint pdf is given by the red-shaded area:
[image]

So as you may see, when $0<y\le 1$ you integrate from $0$ to $y$ and when $y > 1$ you integrate from $0$ to $1$

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat*: This solution came from playing around with this distribution trying to decompose it into a function of two independent random variables. I think it's neat, but certainly not the standard way to approach things.

*Observation:* With a little bit of work (basically just change of variables), you can show that if you set $A=X^2,B=X^2/Y^2$, then $A,B$ are independent $U[0,1]$ random variables. Equivalently, if you start with such $A,B$ and set $(X,Y)=\left(\sqrt{A},\sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}\right)$, this will follow the same distribution as the initial distribution given in the question.

Then:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\le y)=\mathbb{P}\left(\sqrt{\frac{A}{B}}\le y\right)=\mathbb{P}(A\le By^2)$$

$$=\mathbb{E}_B\mathbb{P}(A\le By^2|B)=\mathbb{E}_B(By^2\wedge1)$$

$$=\int_0^1(by^2\wedge1)\,db=y^2\int_0^1(b\wedge y^{-2})\,db$$

$$=\begin{cases}
y^2\int_0^1b\,db=\frac{1}{2}y^2\text{ for } y<1\\
y^2\left[\int_0^{y^{-2}}b\,db+y^{-2}\left(1-y^{-2}\right)\right]=y^2\left[\frac{1}{2y^4}+y^{-2}-y^{-4}\right]=1-\frac{1}{2y^2} \text{ for } y>1
\end{cases}$$

Differentation yields the sought density function.